# Facebook Facepile users liked vs connected

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I noticed that the Facebook Facepile plugin shows my friends who 'Liked' the page on some apps while it shows my friends who 'Connected' to the app on others.

How do I choose which one Facepile shows?

I am aware that I can assign a custom action to Facepile. If I want to show friends that have connected/authorized the app, does that mean I need to create a new action called "connect"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the facepile social plugin documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/

> To display users who have liked your page, specify the URL of your
>   page as the href parameter. To display users who have signed up for
>   your site, specify your application id as the app_id parameter.

Comment: I have to learn to read carefully. I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: I've specified my app id (with no URL), but the Facepile is only showing my friends who have signed up for my the site. I want to display the count of all users (friends or not). Is this possible?